# $_GET not working in PHP file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to get details that are parsed to a URL from my `PHP` script. I understand that I have to use the `$_GET` to fetch the details. Currently, I have two php files: one ends in `.php` while the other shows as a normal url without the file extension.
In these my files, I already have the `$_GET` keyword, but it is only the file that has the `.php` extension that seems to fetch the details from the URL. The other file (still a php file) without the file extension shown in the browser tab, does not fetch the details using the same $_GET function.

Here's my `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2    [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3    [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4    [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4&fifthvar=$5    [NC,L]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4&fifthvar=$5&sixthvar=$6    [NC,L]
```

And this is an example of the URL that I am trying to fetch the details:
`http://www.example.com/page?edit=xxx`.
I have already checked some of the similar links but none of the solutions provided could resolve the issue. What could be causing this problem?

Comment: You put PHP code into a file without a `.php` extension? This file is not parsed by your web server - by intention. I see you referring only to `index.php`, does everything work there?

Comment: None of your rewrite rules will have any effect on the request url `http://www.example.com/page?edit=xxx`. Also, if you want the existing query string to be included in the rewritten URL, you will need to add [QSA](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to the flags.

Comment: What I meant by *without the `.php` extension* is that the extension is not shown in the browser address bar. And yes, every other thing works there. The challenge is that if I call the file directly, let's say `http://www.example.com/page.php?edit=xxx`, the detail will be fetched correctly using the `$_GET` function, but if it is just a clean URL like `http://www.example.com/page?edit=xxx`, nothing is fetched.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage, I have tried adding the QSA tag to the rules, but not working either. This was what I did: `RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1 [NC] [QSA]` and so on, but nothing worked. Do I need to remove the [NC] tags for it to work?

Comment: I have read your post twice but still could not understand what you want to achive..? do you want to remove .php extension so that example.com/file?q=foo can also work without .php extension?

Comment: Exactly @Starkeen, and I've been able to do that by adding the `QSA` tag to my `Rewrite` rule. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome , +1 for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I added to fix the issue:

```
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4&fifthvar=$5    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  index.php?firstvar=$1&secondvar=$2&thirdvar=$3&fourthvar=$4&fifthvar=$5&sixthvar=$6    [NC,L,QSA]
```

Thanks everyone for you effort.